# Upload a file to filesystem and then store details on a datatable

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm coding a view to upload a file, the user may choose between upload it to the filesystem or upload it to the filesystem and record the filename on a datatable.

At this moment, the first stage (upload it to the filesystem only) is working, regards to the second option, the file is uploaded to the directory but I can't add the filename info to the table; I am confuse with these 2 facts: 1) I am getting this error: finfo_file(/tmp/phpKB2h1A): failed to open stream: No such file or directory, 2) the var (tplfilename) is blank

This is the View:

```php
<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>
    <?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('sminfo2')): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('sminfo2');?>
        </div>

    <?php else: ?>

        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'tplfilename')->fileInput()->label('Choose your Template',['class'=>'label-class']) ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'destination')->radioList(array('1'=>'Filesystem','2'=>'Datatable'))->label('File store destination:') ?>

        <button>Submit</button>
        <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

This is the controller's function:

```php
    public function actionUploadtpl(){ 
        $model = new UploadtplForm();
        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $model->destination = $_POST['UploadtplForm']['destination'];
            $model->tplfilename = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'tplfilename'); 
            if($model->destination == "1"){

                if ($model->upload()) {
                    // file is uploaded successfully
                    Yii::$app->session->setFlash("sminfo2", "Template file uploaded successfully to Filesystem");
                    return $this->refresh();                                            
                    //return;
                }//end of if model upload
            }//end of if model destination ==1
            else{
                if($model->upload()){
                    $model->save();
                    Yii::$app->session->setFlash("sminfo2", "Template file uploaded successfully to Datatable");
                    return $this->refresh();                                                     
                }
            }  
        }//end of isPost
        return $this->render('uploadtpl', ['model' => $model]);
    }//end of uploadtplform
```

And this is the model:

```php
<?php
namespace app\models;

use Yii;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

/**
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $tplfilename
**/

//class UploadtplForm extends Model
class UploadtplForm extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $tplfilename; //upload filename
    public $destination; //set by user on view: upload the file to filesystem or datatable    

    public static function tableName(){
        return 'templates';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['tplfilename'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'php'],
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        /*
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->tplFile->saveAs('mail/views' . $this->tplFile->baseName . '.' . $this->tplFile->extension);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        */
            //store using filesystem
            $this->tplfilename->saveAs('../mail/views/' . $this->tplfilename->baseName . '.' . $this->tplfilename->extension);
            return true;                    
    }//end of upload function

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'tplfilename' => 'File name',
         ];
    }

}
?>
```

I would like to have your comments about how to achieve to upload the file and record the filename on the data table, most of the issue is about this line: $model->save().

Comment: But you not doing anything to return or to assign value in the model to filename. You return true or false. You have to return in your model `$this->tplfilename->baseName . '.' . $this->tplfilename->extension`, in to var or model->tplfilename and save it in case of chousing the `store`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my model like an example:

```
/*
     * Upload image
     * @params $url Url where to upload
     * @return filename
     */
    public function upload($url, $image_name)
    {
        try{
            if ($this->validate()) {                 
                $this->imageFile->saveAs($url . $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension);
                if($image_name){
                    FileHelper::unlink($url . $image_name);
                }
                return $this->imageFile->baseName . '.' . $this->imageFile->extension;
            }
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            throw new Exception("Error while upload file.");
            return false;
        }
```

Here is my controller:

```
/**
     * Upload image for product.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function Upload(UploadedFile $object, $name = null)
    {
        $user_id = $this->getUser()->id;
        $model = new UploadForm();
        $model->imageFile = $object;
        $path = Yii::getAlias('@frontend/uploads/user-files/user-') . $user_id;
        //check if dirrectory exist
        if ( ! is_dir($path)) {
            FileHelper::createDirectory($path);
        }
        $url = $path . '/';

        return $model->upload($url, $name);
    }
```

and here i call my method from action and save the model:

```
$cart_item_option->option_type_value = $this->Upload(UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('image'), null);
$cart_item_option->save();
```

Comment: thanks for your comment Serghei, finally I solved the problem redesigned the entire process of upload a file and save the info on a datatable, it is working great, I would like to share the solution here but unfortunately it was marked as duplicated, I posted an update of my approach but it was deleted, as many questions on Stackoverflow, future users will not be able to test a solution that solved the question.